# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express - project creation failed

Tags: visual-c++, project, creation

When I try to create a new project, it says:
Creating project 'example'... project creation failed.

I tried to reinstall, it didn't work, I googled about the error, and all the answers for VCExpress 2008.
There are some people who asked about the error for 2010, but nobody answered them.

I'm using Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Barring the usual caveats regarding write permissions on the folder you want to create the project, and bad installs, make sure that your anti-virus software (current and/or previous) is not getting in the way.

In my case even though I had uninstalled Mcafee, there was still a big chunk of it still running on my system. Once I uninstalled it completely (using the McAfee Consumer Product Removal Tool) and rebooted everything worked fine.